# How to add an object to a vector and check if it worked

Tags: c++, vector

I got a class WayPoint that contains a pair of doubles and a name.
I got a class WayPointContainer that contains a vector of Waypoints.

WayPointContainer got a method to add a WayPoint to its vector and a Print Method to show the WayPoints inside the vector. I implemented both but dont know how to check if it works. My Print Method does not print any WayPointName. So either my **Add** method or my **Print** method is wrong.

So as soon as i call the Add method **c1->Add(*p1)** of WayPointContainer the programm stops.
i tryd different version using insert() of vector with iterator. I also tryd printing the capacity but every method just leads to a programm stop so i guess something with initialisation is wrong ?
I got the header files from my prof so i am hoping they are correct. And since he doesnt answer me i try it here.

I tryd debugging it but i find the information given by debugging really hard to read and use. I also tryd different implementations of the methods but it was always the same result.

WayPoint.h

```
#ifndef WAYPOINT_H_
#define WAYPOINT_H_
#include <iostream>

namespace HHN {

class WayPoint {
private:
    std::string name{ "" };
    std::pair<double, double> coords{ 0.0, 0.0 };
public:
    WayPoint();
    virtual ~WayPoint();
    WayPoint(const WayPoint& orig);
    WayPoint(const std::string& xName, double xCoord, double yCoord);

    WayPoint& operator=(const WayPoint& rhs);

    std::string Name() const;
    double first() const;
    double second() const;
};

} /* namespace HHN */

#endif /* WAYPOINT_H_ */
```

WayPoint.cpp

```
#include "WayPoint.h"

namespace HHN {

WayPoint::WayPoint() {}

WayPoint::~WayPoint() {}

WayPoint::WayPoint(const WayPoint& orig) {}

WayPoint::WayPoint(const std::string& xName, double xCoord, double yCoord) {
    this->name = xName;
    this->coords.first = xCoord;
    this->coords.second = yCoord;
}

WayPoint& WayPoint::operator =(const WayPoint& rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) {
        return *this;
    }
    else {
        this->coords.first = rhs.first();
        this->coords.second = rhs.second();
        this->name = rhs.Name();
    }
    return *this;
}

std::string WayPoint::Name() const {
    return name;
}

double WayPoint::first() const {
    return this->coords.first;
}

double WayPoint::second() const {
    return this->coords.second;
}

} /* namespace HHN */
```

WayPointContainer.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "WayPoint.h"

#ifndef WAYPOINTCONTAINER_H_
#define WAYPOINTCONTAINER_H_

class WayPointContainer {
private:
    std::vector<HHN::WayPoint>* pContainer{nullptr};
public:
    WayPointContainer();
    WayPointContainer(const WayPointContainer& orig);
    virtual ~WayPointContainer();

    WayPointContainer& operator=(const WayPointContainer& rhs);
    HHN::WayPoint& operator[](int idx) const;

    void Add(const HHN::WayPoint& arg);
    int Size() const;
    void Print() const;
};

#endif /* WAYPOINTCONTAINER_H_ */
```

WayPointContainer.cpp

```
#include "WayPointContainer.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

WayPointContainer::WayPointContainer() {
    pContainer = new std::vector<HHN::WayPoint>;
}

WayPointContainer::WayPointContainer(const WayPointContainer& orig) {
    pContainer = orig.pContainer;
}

WayPointContainer::~WayPointContainer() {
    delete[] pContainer;
}

WayPointContainer& WayPointContainer::operator =(const WayPointContainer& rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) {
            return *this;
        }
    else {
        pContainer = rhs.pContainer;
    }
    return *this;
}

HHN::WayPoint& WayPointContainer::operator [](int idx) const {
    return (*pContainer)[idx];
}

void WayPointContainer::Add(const HHN::WayPoint& arg) {
    this->pContainer->push_back(arg);
}

int WayPointContainer::Size() const {
    return pContainer->size();
}

void WayPointContainer::Print() const {
    for (auto waypoint = pContainer->begin(); waypoint != pContainer->end(); ++waypoint) {
            auto tmp = waypoint->Name();
            cout << tmp << " <- Name" << "\n";
        }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "WayPoint.h"
#include "WayPointContainer.h"

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;

    HHN::WayPoint *p1 = new HHN::WayPoint("nameOfP1",1.5,1.5);  // works
    HHN::WayPoint *p2(p1);                              // works

    WayPointContainer *c1 = new WayPointContainer();    // works
    WayPointContainer *c2(c1);                          // works
    WayPointContainer *c3 = new WayPointContainer();

    c1->Add(*p1);
    c1->Print();

    cout << " Punkt1: " << p1->Name() << " "<< p1->first() << " " << p1->second() << "\n";

    cout << "!!!Hello World out!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The console output i am getting is :

```
!!!Hello World!!!
 <- Name
 Punkt1: nameOfP1 1.5 1.5
!!!Hello World out!!!
```

but i am expecting

```
!!!Hello World!!!
 nameOfP1 <- Name
 Punkt1: nameOfP1 1.5 1.5
!!!Hello World out!!!
```

(This is actually a task from my prof to implement the header files given. And since he ignored my mails so far i am trying it here. I am pretty sure this is something very small and probably obvious to fix but i am very much a beginner of C++ and struggle alot. I am sitting already days on that implementation.)

Comment: You should take a look at [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: The `pContainer` member variable being a pointer to a std::vector is not a good design. This has lead to several bugs. Your copy constructor and copy-assignment operator will make both containers point to the same std::vector. I don't think you want changes of one container to appear in both. This will also lead to double delete errors when they're destroyed. You destructor uses `delete[]` when it should just be `delete`. My advice is to stop using pointers and `new`. They aren't needed anywhere in this code and are just causing bugs and memory leaks.

Comment: Just a small update. I printed out where the pointers point to (hex values) to compare the vectors of the objects and i realized that my copy constructor of WayPointContainer.cpp was wrong. With this implementation it works: ```pContainer = new std::vector<HHN::WayPoint>(*orig.pContainer);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting a copy of WayPoint into the container, but you missed implementing a copy constructor.

```
void WayPointContainer::Add(const HHN::WayPoint& arg) {
// push_pack do copy object
    this->pContainer->push_back(arg);
}
```

```
WayPoint::WayPoint(const WayPoint& orig) {}
```

Try to implement copy constructor.

```
WayPoint::WayPoint(const WayPoint& orig) {
    name = orig.name;
    coords.first = orig.coords.first;
    coords.second = orig.coords.second;
}
```

Comment: You are right thanks i completely missed that. Now i only have to get the destructor part right because if i delete pContainer of C1 while C2 = C1 the pContainer of C2 will also be deleted.